# Do we need to write logs in a file for a Spring Boot application to be deployed on AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, logging, lombok

I have never configured logging in Java, so far only worked on projects where logging was already configured. Now I am starting a spring boot project on my own, taking some help from existing projects. 2 such projects were using log4j2:

1. A spring boot project deployed on an EC2 instance. This project had a `log4j2.xml` file that configures writing logs in a file. We can see the logs of this app in the cloudwatch too, though nothing related to cloudwatch is specified in xml config.
2. A maven project deployed serverless on Lambda. This uses log4j2.xml as well. Similarly we can see logs in cloudwatch, but it has no config related to writing logs to file. But this project has this part in it, not sure what it does:

```xml
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="software.amazon.awssdk" level="WARN"/>
    <Logger name="software.amazon.awssdk.request" level="DEBUG"/>
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to know:

1. Do we really need to write logs to a file when using AWS? Can't we simply see logs or query them in the Cloudwatch logs?
2. I am using lombok for logging, simply using annotations over the class and I can directly log stuff. So far I can see logs on my console, the app is not deployed in any environment. Is it important to use an xml log configuration file to show logs on cloudwatch when this app will be deployed on AWS? What's the use of an xml file here? I have read on many blogs that an xml file is recommended nevertheless.

Comment: Nothing like trying it out but, afaik, in AWS, all you have to do is to stdout your logs and you will have them in Cloudwatch.

Comment: The example you showed below 2) configures Loggers with in the given packages to log everything from the specified level and upwards. For example, a Logger for `software.amazon.awssdk.Example` will discard all logs with a level lower than `WARN`, however a logger for `software.amazon.awssdk.request.Example` will not discard any logs (since `DEBUG` is the lowest level)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, while using a cloud environment such AWS, it does not make sense to use a file. Different instances of a microservice will be running on a different machine/process at the time of execution. Therefore, it is necessary to make use of centralized logging frameworks  (as you mentioned) such as splunk where every instance could write log messages. Such frameworks will provide functionality to consolidate logs from every instance.